# How to loop with index check and double bangs?

Tags: javascript

The following works very well, as an alternative for length check.

```
import { range } from 'lodash';

const items = range(10);

let i = -1;

while (items[++i] != undefined) {
  console.log(items[i]);
}
```

but if it is changed to `while (!!items[++i])` it hangs. Is there a way to keep this short hand way of boolean checking without explicit `undefined` check?

```
let i = -1;

while (!!items[++i]) {
  console.log(items[i]);
// this seems not terminating
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition checks whether the item is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). It terminates immediately because `0`, the first item in the array returned by [`_.range`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range), is falsy.

In this case, you can explicitly allow `0`:

```js
const items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let i = -1;

while (!!items[++i] || items[i] == 0) {
  console.log(items[i]);
}
```

**Edit**: to accordance to your newly specified needs:

```js
const items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let i = -1;

while (items.hasOwnProperty(++i)) {
  console.log(items[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to check a valid index rather than checking for the value in that position?

Comment: @kdd I mean, isn't what you were trying to do already "checking for the value in that position?"

Comment: No. If you want to generalize instead of numbers, cause sometimes some indices can be falsey. The only idea is to get rid of length check and keep the shorthand version (!!items[++i]), without relying on the underlying value, i.e., just to check whether the index is occupied so that the loop terminates without hanging.

Comment: I found a another alt. ```while (!!items[++i] ?? !!0)```

Comment: my idea was to genearalize the iteration for any array ```[1,0, undefined, null, {}, false, '',true]``` and keep a shorthand version without length checking. this way it doesnot rely on the underlying value, but only checks if the index is occupied or not. (so it should work for undefined and null values in an array). The main goal is to remove the length check as a criteria for terminating the loop and use the above mentioned shorthand version. May sound a bit crazy, but I was exploring some alternatives!

Comment: @kdd I've updated my answer. Essentially, you can use the `hasOwnProperty` method to check whether the array has an item at that index.

Comment: Is it performant compared to the shorthand version of mine?

Comment: @kdd Well yes, its time complexity is `O(1)`. Under the hood, it's just a simple check